# FluentValidation not honoring my CSS class addition

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I just implemented `FluentValidation`, everything seems awesome except one awkward little detail.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "create-post" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text, new { @class = "post-input" })
    @Html.Validation(m => m.Text)
    <input type="submit" value="@Html.Resource("Publish")" />
}

    public static MvcHtmlString Validation<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
    {
        return helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, null, Resources.Constants.ModelValidationMessageCssClass);
    }
```

With the default implementation from ASP.NET MVC 3, this created an `<span>` that had whatever class the validator deemed appropriate AND `input-validation` (which is the one from my resource). `FluentValidation` seems to just ignore this setting. Any idea how I can add a CSS class selector to the span generated by `FluentValidation`?

On a similar note, take for example this output it produces:

```
<form method="post" class="create-post" action="/posts/create" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" value="" name="Text" id="Text" data-val-required="complete this!" data-val-regex-pattern="long-stuff" data-val-regex="wrong regex!" data-val="true" class="post-input input-validation-error">
    <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Text" class="field-validation-error">
        <span for="Text" generated="true" class="">wrong regex!</span>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="Publicar!">
</form>
```

I feel I'm back in ASP.NET WebForms here :( .. , how can I remove stuff like `novalidate="true"` or the `generated="true"` attribute? I'm fine with `data` attributes, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing I think is causing trouble is your Validation extension method.  It calls ValidationMessageFor, which is an MVC3 extension on the HTML helper, but with a signature that would match passing it the validation message instead:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>
    (this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string validationMessage)
```

Based on your code, I would actually expect the error message to be the CSS class name in your resource, based on this snippet from how the `<span>` is generated:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage)) {
        builder.SetInnerText(validationMessage);
    }
    else if (modelError != null) {
        builder.SetInnerText(GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, modelState));
    }
```

So **you probably want to modify your extension** to something like (if it doesn't get overruled):

```
public static MvcHtmlString Validation<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
{
    return helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression, null, null, new { _class = Resources.Constants.ModelValidationMessageCssClass });
}
```

**Bottom line though, I don't think FluentValidation has anything to do with the markup generated** - it should only be feeding your validation errors to ModelState, and ASP.NET MVC is doing the rest.  **If you want to take even more control you could just write your own HTML tag builder**; I grabbed most of this from the [MVC3 source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781), so you could follow their patterns or go a different way.  You can also reference the [FluentValidation source](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) for some more insights.

Comment: Can I provide my own tag builders? is there a tag builder factory I can inject my own versions to?

Comment: None that I saw in the ValidationMessageFor guts.  Tags are built around flow control over things like whether or not you have unobtrusive JavaScript enabled, but no other real extensibility points.